Why might the NKJV put "them all" where the ESV puts "all" in Romans 11:32?
Romans 11:32 NKJV

"For God has committed them all to disobedience, that He might have mercy on all." [My emphasis.]

I think "them all" here refers to just Israel.
Romans 11:32 ESV

"For God has consigned all to disobedience, that he may have mercy on all."

Here "all", I reckon, refers to all nations.
What translation issues might be behind NKJV "them all"  but ESV "all"?

It may be a theological translation (ie, motivated by theology) rather than text.  However, it is best asked of the translators.

@Dottard Grammatically does, or could, "them" refer to "these" v31? "these also have now been disobedient".

You have gotten to the heart of the matter and that is what is wrong with the NKJV translation - "them" would refer only to the disobedient in V31; BUT that is NOT what the Greek says in V32.  The Greek actually says, "For God has consigned everyone to disobedience ..."

The OP states, “I think 'them all' here refers to just Israel.” The word translated as “them all” in the NKJV is πᾶς (Strong’s G3956 meaning all, every). The word πᾶς is considered to be a pronominal adjective, an adjective that can also act as a pronoun – which is how it is used in Romans 11:32. Specifically, the parsing of πᾶς in Rom 11:32 is accusative, masculine, plural. It does not modify a noun but functions as an indefinite pronoun that comes with a definite article, which is generally left untranslated. Literally, τοὺς πάντας means “the all.”
Romans 11:32
συνέκλεισεν     …   τοὺς  πάντας
has bound up         -    all

Compare the way Rom 11:32 is constructed to Mt 12:15 and Rom 11:26. In Mt 12:15, “all” is an adjective that modifies the pronoun “them.” In Rom 11:26, “all” modifies “Israel.” Note that there is less ambiguity in these other constructions.
Matthew 12:15
ἐθεράπευσεν     αὐτοὺς  πάντας
[he] healed     them    all

Romans 11:26
πᾶς         Ἰσραὴλ      σωθήσεται
all         Israel      will be saved

Consider also Jn 12:32. Here, πᾶς functions as a pronoun, one that is also accusative masculine plural but without the article.
John 12:32
πάντας    ἑλκύσω
all men   [I] will draw

Whatever the antecedent of τοὺς πάντας in Romans 11:32 may be, it is generally not understood to reference the same group as the “they” in verse 31. In other words, it does not refer to only Israel. According to Thayer's, the masculine plural of πᾶς when used without a substantive and with the definite article means "all collectively" either of all men or of a certain definite whole. It interprets Rom 11:32 as referencing all men.
Thayer’s Greek Lexicon

οἱ πάντες, all taken together, all collectively (cf. Winer's Grammar,
116 (110)): of all men, Romans 11:32; of a certain definite whole,
Philippians 2:21;

Compare the way Rom 11:32 is constructed to Rom 11:36. Though πᾶς in v36 is neuter in gender, note that it also has the article, literally “the all things.”
Romans 11:36
εἰς         αὐτὸν   τὰ  πάντα
unto        him     -  [are] all things

The OP asks, “Why might the NKJV put 'them all' where the ESV puts 'all' in Romans 11:32?” Translations that render τοὺς πάντας as “all” leave open the possibility that τοὺς πάντας refers to all men. Whatever the intention and whoever the antecedent of “them” may be, rendering τοὺς πάντας as “them all” in effect hinders the interpretation of τοὺς πάντας as referring to all men.
Within the context of Romans 11, an alternative view of τοὺς πάντας is that it refers to a whole that is comprised of two parts: Jews and Gentiles.
Cambridge commentary

“All” must manifestly be taken here, as so often elsewhere, (see on
ch. Romans 5:18,) with limitation. St Paul is contemplating not the
whole race, but the whole Church in its two great elements—Gentile and
Jewish. See Romans 2:8-9, for his distinct warning of a “judgment
without mercy” on the impenitent and unbelieving, Gentiles and Jews
alike.

Looking at the broader context of Paul’s letter to the Romans, perhaps there is not that great of a difference between these alternative interpretations of τοὺς πάντας. If “all” is conceived to be a totality made up of two parts, Jews and Gentiles, those two could still be viewed as representative of all men, or as Meyer’s commentary puts it, of the “two halves of mankind in the gross.”
Meyer’s commentary

ΤΟῪς ΠΆΝΤΑς] Of Gentiles (ὙΜΕῖς) and Jews (ΟὟΤΟΙ) Paul has previously
spoken; hence ΟἹ ΠΆΝΤΕς now comprises the totality, namely all Jews
and Gentiles jointly and severally,—“cunctos s. universos, i. e.
singulos in unum corpus colligatos,” Ellendt, Lex. Soph. II. p. 521.
Comp. on the subject-matter, Romans 3:9; Romans 3:19; Galatians 3:22.
So necessarily also the following τοὺς πάντας. The view which
understands only the two masses of Jews and Gentiles, these two halves
of mankind in the gross (usually so taken recently, as by Tholuck,
Fritzsche, Philippi, Ewald, Weiss),


Thanks. You say, "Rom 11:32 is interpreted according to the first". I am not sure what "the first" refers to. Is it "all of mankind" with "all men" as "second"? Maybe I keep misreading.

Sorry for the lack of clarity. Thayer's lexicon interprets Ro 11:32 as pertaining to all men collectively. I understand that to mean all mankind.

This is a complicated question that I've tried to respond to as succinctly as I can. While Thayer's definition is helpful, it fails to fully explain how the article affects the meaning of πάντας. Granted, the construction in Ro 11:32 is uncommon in the NT and usage patterns are ambiguous. Take Ph 2:21. It seems to me that the article in Ph 2:21 punctuates the fact that Paul is making a general statement about all men, which is not to say that there are no exclusions. But that is my own interpretation. I could not find much information on the specific nuances of this particular construction.

Ph 2:21 has been invoked as an example of why the construction in question should not be taken in an absolute sense. But if we compare how the article affects the meaning of the neuter plural, it raises questions about how the article should be understood when applied to the masculine plural. Thayer's has this to say about the neuter plural: "τά πάντα; αα. in an absolute sense, all things collectively, the totality of created things, the universe of things." Just to be clear, I am speaking only of the pronoun/substantival use πᾶς.

One question I keep asking myself is: If the thought in Ro 11:32 could be expressed without the  use of the articles, why then were the articles included in the text? What nuance do they add to the meaning? Given the exegetical significance of the verse, I'd welcome any input or insight that you or anyone else may have to offer.

I acknowledge your last 3 comments and look forward to further clarity in time.

συνέκλεισεν γὰρ ὁ θεὸς ⸂τοὺς πάντας⸃ εἰς ἀπείθειαν, 
ἵνα τοὺς πάντας ἐλεήσῃ*. (28th Edition, Rom. 11:32, NA28)

Basically, there is no difference in meaning between "them all" and "all" here.  It's a matter of fitting the English at the time of translation.  πᾶς, πᾶσα, πᾶν gen. παντός, πάσης, παντός are grammatic forms of the adjective and can be used as a noun as here.  Sometimes we need to add a pronoun when an adjective is used as a noun for it to make sense.  For example, if this adjective were singular, it would be every, but if masculine and used as a noun, for it to make sense to us, we would translate it everyone, and if neuter used as a noun everything.  Thus, we added one or thing.  For us the accusative masculine plural τοὺς πάντας makes sense translated "all," but in the time of the KJV they needed "them all" to make sense.
